# How do I create console commands for my module or plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, modules, yii, console

I would like to create a custom console command for my Craft 3 plugin. I've looked at the Yii docs and understand commands are defined using controllers extending `\yii\console\Controller` but cannot work out how these controllers should be registered with the application.

To register site routes in Craft 3, we listen for the `UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES` event and then define rules. What's the equivalent for registering console commands?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the equivalent for registering console commands?

You don't need to listen to an event to create a console command. Assuming your namespacing and autoloading is set up correctly, they'll "just work".

I'd suggest going over to https://pluginfactory.io/ and select with Craft 3 plugin or module and tick the "Console Commands" checkbox to see a working example of how the files and structure is set up.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the tip! I looked at the fantastic SEO plugin to see the correct structure (https://github.com/ethercreative/seo/blob/v3/src/console/controllers/UpgradeController.php).